# how to empty the value of an edittext on a click

Tags: android

for example, if I have 9 edittext how I can dump the value of a selected edittext and the others not
for example edittext1 = 1, edittext2 = 2, edittext3 = 3, edittext4 = 4,  edittext5 = 5, edittext6 = 6, edittext7 = 7, edittext8 = 8, edittext9 = 9
here I want to erase 1 and the other number remains

I need your help

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

First method:

```
edittext1.setText("");
```

Second method:

```
edittext1.getText().clear();
```

You can do this whenever you press a button or select an `editText`...for example this will clear your editText when you click it

```
edittext1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        edittext1.getText().clear();
    }
});
```

Also, if you want to prevent the software keyboard from popping up just add this when you declare your editText

```
edittext1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Happy coding!

Comment: merci Gaston Saillén     yes I tried with that but when you click on the button all the value of 9 edittext will be empty

Comment: tell me if that worked and i will be so glad if you check my answer :) happy coding !

Comment: they should not be empty as you are only clearing the text from the edittext1

Comment: do you have any programmed button or anything more ? can you provide code in your question ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

When click edittext that time get data and clear that data and also directly to set value on editext box click event.

```
 editText1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editText1.setText("");
            editText1.getText().clear();

        }
    });
```